# how to run CorePlot examples?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-plot

I am trying to run CorePlot's CPTTestApp-iPhone example project and it fails to build.
It is giving me the following error:

"Operand of ? changes signedness: 'int' to 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')" in the line of code
`NSUInteger loc            = MAX(0, (NSInteger)range.location - expandBy);`
in "CPTUtilities.m"

Any ideas on why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue and has been fixed. Take a look:

http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=501&can=1&sort=-id